# Store.getGroups returns an array of undefined objects in Extjs 5.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I am stuck in one situation where I have to expand the selected row of group grid made in Extjs 5.1. But Store.getGroups returns an array of undefined objects,

Can any one had a similar issue, as this was working fine with Extjs 4.2.x?

Fiddle code - works in 4.2.x, doesn't work in 5.1

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8mi

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getGroups()` method returns a [Ext.util.Collection](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.util.Collection-method-getSorters)

You could easily get the the first group name the following way:

```
var firstGroupName = store.getGroups().getAt(0).getGroupKey();
```

Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6etv535/1/).

To get all groups use the `getRange()` method.

```
var groups = store.getGroups().getRange();
```

Comment: FWIW, the "undefined" part is a way that Chrome represents empty arrays that have user-defined properties. Essentially, someone at Sencha initialised an object using [] instead of {}